# Sockets, Get Number of Bytes Available (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, c#-2.0

Good afternoon,

OK, short and sweet.

I need to get the number of bytes available for read from a socket. I have setup a NetworkStream on my Socket Client but can't seem to find how to get the number of bytes that are available to be read, at the moment I can only get a boolean stating "Yes I have Bytes", or "No Bytes this time". But this is all but useful for the task I require.

Could anyone put me out of my misery and provide me with my need?

Thanks in advance, appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As specified in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.length(VS.71).aspx) about the `NetworkStream.Length` property:

> Gets the length of the data available on the stream. This property always throws a `NotSupportedException`.

This is due to the fact that data is fed to the stream as it arrives, thus having no actual length.

However, the [`Socket.Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(VS.71).aspx) property tells you how many bytes are available to be read at **this exact moment**. The value may change at any given time if new data arrives.

Answer (score 4):

[Socket.Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available.aspx)